Transformations of Function
Im having trouble conceptualizing why when we transform a function, we need to describe $x$ and $y$ as functions in the new coordinate system. For example with polar coordinates $x$ and $y$ are now functions of $\theta$ and $r$. That’s intuitive because of trigonometry, but in more general systems let’s say as an example transforming a triangle into some other skewed shape in the new coordinate systems $uv$-plane.
Now $u$ becomes a function of $x$ and $y$, and $v$ becomes a function of $x$ and $y$, but why is this the case, why do we have to describe $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x$ and $y$? Can anyone give me a simplistic answer, I’m not very mathematically mature.

Honestly I don't understand your question, "why do we have to describe u and v as functions of x and y?". That's just the way a change of variable works, you do that in order to change your coordinate system, so you express new coordinates using the old coordinates.

As in conceptually, what is the reason behind it. I understand why we must do it for polar coordinates intuitively because of trigonometry, but for generally why?

You are not forced to do it for polar coordinates, you do it if you need it to achieve some result that otherwise would be harder, or even just to explore. There is no obligation to do something like that, so I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.

Like for an example when we have a  parralelogram, and we want to transform it into a square, so it’s easier to integrate. We transform it to the uv plane, and now T(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y)) which represents the points in this rectangle in the uv plane. My question is why does x and y have an effect on the u value? and vice versa?

What do you mean by "why does x and y have an effect on the u value?". How would you describe $u$ if not in terms of $x$ and $y$?

I will give you a concrete example to see why does this make sense:

$\textbf{Question}$:Let $D$ be the closed region surrounded by the $x$ axis, the $y$ axis, and $x+y=2$. Then compute $\iint_{D}e^{\frac{y-x}{x+y}}dxdy.$

This double integral is not easy to solve (maybe cannot be solved using ordinary method). But if letting $\begin{cases} y-x=u\\ y+x=v\end{cases}$, then the integral becomes $\iint_{D'}e^{\frac{u}{v}}\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}dudv$, where $D'$ is the closed region surrounded by $v=u, v=-u$ and $v=2$, which becomes much easier.
